# jQuery Toggle (Expanding Div) Inconsistent Transition With Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got my expanding div working, however it seems the transition opens abruptly on divs with text, yet closes with a smooth transition.  My code is below as is a link to a jsFiddle demo.

How can I get the transition on the open to be as smooth as it demonstrates on the closing?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/phamousphil/s34fA/1/

HTML:

```
        <div class="grid_6 containerExpand collapsedExp">
        <div class="headerExpand"><a href="http://www.google.com">the google</a><br /></div>
        <div class="contentExpand">
        <p>google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!</p><br />
        <p>google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_6 containerExpand collapsedExp">
    <div class="headerExpand"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">YAHOO</a><br /></div>
    <div class="contentExpand">
        <p>Yahoo!.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.containerExpand {
}

.headerExpand {
cursor: pointer;
}

.headerExpand:hover {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.collapsedExp .headerExpand {
}

.collapsedExp .headerExpand:hover {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.contentExpand {
height: auto;
min-height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.collapsedExp .contentExpand {
min-height: 0px;
height: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.headerExpand').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.containerExpand').toggleClass('collapsedExp');
        $(".headerExpand").find("a").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified approach to your code that seems to test well.

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/82Tg9/)

HTML:

```
<div class="heading">the google</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!</p><br />
    <p>google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!  google stuff google stuff google stuff!</p>
</div>

<div class="heading">YAHOO</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Yahoo!.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.heading {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.heading:hover {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(300);
});
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: This fixes the animation problem perfectly, I'll need to change how my plus/minus image change works with the JQuery but I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! By plus/minus do you mean time interval or speed? If so, you change the number in this part .slideToggle(300); to adjust.

Comment: Sorry, plus/minus was the images used.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When transitioning the browser must know the boundary of each value so that it knows how to animate correctly.  In your current code when the `div` is expanding, it is transitioning from `0px` to `100px` (the min-height) because those are the known values.  Once the transition is complete, the browser resizes the `div` to fit around the text.  I do not know a great way to achieve the exact effect you desire, but here are a couple of options:

1. Set the height: if the text in your `div`s are relatively similar, set `height: 150px` (or similar) in the contentExpand class
2. Change the font-size:

   `.collapsedExp .contentExpand {
       min-height: 0px;
       height: 0px;
       font-size: 0;
   }`

Either of these options may work with a light design.  If you are interested in using a heavier framework you might consider Twitter [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which has a popover feature like this, but that might be overkill for what you want.  Good luck!

Comment: #1 created the effect flawlessly, however my div's had inconsistent text amounts ranging from 5 words to two paragraphs, so this solution did not work for my needs.  Thanks for the answer, though!